# Doctrine doesn't recognize column after renaming

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration

I am using PHP 7.4 with the following versions of Doctrine and other tooling (excerpt from `composer.json`):

```
...
"doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
"doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
"doctrine/migrations": "^3.4",
...
```

I am not using Symfony framework.

I created an entity, having the following column annotation:

```php
/**
 * @Column(length=500, nullable=true)
 */
 private ?string $imageRelativePath;
```

After running the migrations, I can see in the database a column called `imageRelativePath`, which is the expected outcome.

After few migrations later, I realized that the naming convention for that column was not desirable, so I changed the annotation to the following:

```php
/**
 * @Column(name="image_relative_path", length=500, nullable=true)
 */
private ?string $imageRelativePath;
```

After doing the migration, I can see that the column in the database is now renamed to `image_relative_path`.

In my DEV environment, I got the whole application working. The problem comes to the PROD environment. After reading from the entity's repository, I get the following error message:
`An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.imageRelativePath' in 'field list`

I tried several ways to clear the Doctrine cache, including:

```sh
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:query
```

and regenerating the proxies as well:

```sh
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies
```

I even went to the extreme of removing the `vendors` folder and reinstalling all the dependencies, but to no avail.

I have other columns which were created with the correct naming convention from the beginning, and I have no problems with them, such as:

```php
/**
 * @var float
 * @Column(name="price_gbp_including_tax", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=4, nullable=false)
*/
private float $priceGBPIncludingTax;
```

I can't see any actual difference between these two examples, other than the type specifics of the column.

My questions are:

1. How come the column's old name is still referenced
2. How come this behaviour only shows up in PROD
3. Is it possible to replicate this behaviour in DEV

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, since I seem to have found what the issue is.

It turns out that my system is configured by default to use [private temps](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-67-why-the-files-in-tmp-directory-gets-deleted-periodically/). Because of this, doctrine cache files where stored somewhere in `\tmp\systemd-private-<hash>-php-fmp.service-<hash>` directory, and not in `\tmp` folder root.

And it seems like (I didn't confirm it yet) the command `$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata` deletes the cache files in `\tmp` folder.

Manually deleting the cache in the private temp will actually fix the problem

Moving forward, disabling the [private temporary folder generation](https://upwork.link/servers-of-web-apache2/centos7-how-do-disable-privatetmp-for-apache-with-systemd/) should fix the issue